# how pass variable in pentaho mongodb input query(aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to use variable substitution in MongoDB input with aggregation. But this is not working.
EX:
db.fch.aggregate([
{$match:{'date_field':{$gte:"***${lastOneHour}***"}}},
...
${lastOneHour} varible value coming from a parameter.

Comment: Do you have this variable declared in the Parameters tab of the KTR ?

Comment: @CristianCurti yes

Answer (score 0):

The following example seem to work in my code:

db.example.find([ { last_modified : { $gte : { $date : "${modified}" } } } ])

and since my find works, I think the following should work in aggregate:

db.fch.aggregate([ {$match:{'date_field':{$gte : { $date : "${lastOneHour}" } } } }])

Make sure the parameter is in "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ" form...